# Cursor highlights everyline on a single click VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, text, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When ever i open VsCode in my PC, It automatically higlights all the lines in that particular file. When i double click it selects the word i clicked on but as soon as I single click on the text it selects everything again.

I have tried Restarting VsCode and my computer but cant seem to figure it out.

Here is a loom to help understand what exactly the problem is

https://www.loom.com/embed/617f4e958e694a09a09fb3fa038649ce

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the SQL Tools extension was highlighting all the queries. so by simply disabling it in the VsCode settings the query highlighting stopped

[SQL Tools Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b97Ri.png)